# Можно удалить url через js?

Tags: javascript

Можно удалить url через js? Например `http://site.ru/index.php?id=123` как сделать так `http://site.ru/index.php`. Как удалить от `?` без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: [html5 history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Comment: @Etki спасибо я знаю не не могу сделать парсинг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = "http://site.ru/index.php?id=123";
var n = s.indexOf("?");
document.body.innerHTML = n >= 0 ? s.substr(0, n) : s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить такой вариант.

```js
var s = "http://site.ru/index.php?id=123";
var n = s.split('?');
//в n[0] - все что до "?", в n[1] - остальное   
document.body.innerHTML = n[0];
```